# Ninject does not resolve dependency correctly in silverlight project

Tags: silverlight, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I have a silverlight 4 project with mvvmlight and ninject 3.x.

I've setup the container like this

```
kernel = new StandardKernel(new ViewModelModule(), new ClientSessionModule());
```

And the modules like this

```
public class ViewModelModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        ((StandardKernel)Kernel)
            .Bind(scanner => scanner.FromThisAssembly()
                            .Select(x  => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ViewModelBase)))
            .BindDefaultInterface());
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ClientSessionModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Kernel.Bind<IClientContext>().To<ClientContext>().InSingletonScope();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is the latter one. At one point in the application this dependency is resolved explictly and updated like this:

```
var context = App.Ioc.Get<IClientContext>();
context.Username = "just a sample name";
```

Now when a ViewModel is loaded it get the IClientContext injected like

```
public MainViewModel(IClientContext clientContext)
```

The problem is that the instance does not have the name set earlier.
But if I inside the same ViewModel resolves explictly again I get the expected instance with the name set.

What am I missing since the sigleton does not get injected as I expected it to be automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a duplicate kernel in my solution. And that explains why I was not able so resolve as expected as I had 2 kernels running